# Accessing List name inside a list as a string in python

Tags: python, string, list

the code which i am trying is as below -

```
IP1_list =['abcd', 'efgh']
IP2_list =['asdf', 'zxcv']
IP3_list =['qwer', 'poiu']

IP_list = [IP1_list, IP2_list, IP3_list]

command_list = [cmd1_IP1, cmd2_IP1, cmd3_IP2, cmd4_IP3]

for i in range(len(command_list)):
    command, IP = cpmmand_list[i].split('_',1)
    if some_var == command:
        for j in range(len(IP_list):
            IP_name, unwanted = IP_list[j].split('_',1)
            if IP_name = IP
                "do something"
```

Note: some_var is the variable I am getting from some other function, which is working fine.

Here in this piece of code I am not able to access the IP_list's elements as string because the elements of it are the lists itself.
for ex: if I execute

```
print IP_list
```

It is printing me all the three lists

How to handle this problem?
I want to access the IP_list's 3 elements as string, so that I can parse it and then compare with the previously extracted variable named IP.

If any other logic one has then it is welcome.
Thanks

Comment: You mean you want to do `print IP_List` and that should give you `["IP1_list", "IP2_list", "IP3_list"]`? This is not possible. Use dictionaries instead:

Answer (score 2):

You can not get the "name" of the variable as a string, you'll access the object directly and it doesn't have a name per sae. However you could switch to a dictionary structure and store the desired name as a `Key` and assign one of your lists to it, like so:

```
IP1_list =['abcd', 'efgh']
IP2_list =['asdf', 'zxcv']
IP3_list =['qwer', 'poiu']

IP_list = {'IP1_list' : IP1_list, 'IP2_list' : IP2_list, 'IP3_list' : IP3_list}


for key in IP_list:
    IP_name, unwanted = key.split('_',1)
        if IP_name == IP:
            "do something"
```

But then again, I'd do:

```
IP_list = {'IP1' : IP1_list, 'IP2' : IP2_list, 'IP3' : IP3_list}
```

and skip

```
IP_name, unwanted = key.split('_',1)
```